# Quagga (Zebra) multiprotocol BGP configuration for IP multicast routing

Tags: routing, vpn, bgp, multicast, quagga

```
Host A: 
Eth1 = Multicast incoming from upstream provider
OpenVPN_interface_point_A = point to point interface with point B
ASN = 100

Host B: 
OpenVPN_interface_point_B = point to point interface with point A
ASN = 200
```

How exactly can I routing specific multicast address from Eth1 to OpenVPN_interface_point_B ?

Both Host A and B are running Quagga BGP version 4 (I know I need to change version 4+, that's not a problem in the future)

PoC Lab:
[image: PoC network diagram]

Router A configuration:

```
routerA# show run

Current configuration:
!
password quagga
!
router bgp 1
 bgp router-id 172.24.0.65
 network 172.24.0.64/30
 neighbor 172.24.0.66 remote-as 2
 neighbor 172.24.0.66 soft-reconfiguration inbound
!
 address-family ipv4 multicast
 network 10.101.16.128/27
 neighbor 172.24.0.66 activate
 exit-address-family
!
line vty
!
end
```

Router A BGP details:

```
routerA# show ip bgp sum
BGP router identifier 172.24.0.65, local AS number 1
RIB entries 1, using 112 bytes of memory
Peers 1, using 4568 bytes of memory

Neighbor        V         AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ Up/Down  State/PfxRcd
172.24.0.66     4     2      35      43        0    0    0 00:17:28        1

Total number of neighbors 1

routerA# show ip bgp ipv4 multicast 
BGP table version is 0, local router ID is 172.24.0.65
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, = multipath,
              i internal, r RIB-failure, S Stale, R Removed
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> 10.101.16.128/27 0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i

Total number of prefixes 1
```

Router B configuration:

```
routerB# show run

Current configuration:
!
password quagga
!
router bgp 2
 bgp router-id 172.24.0.66
 network 172.24.0.64/30
 neighbor 172.24.0.65 remote-as 1
 neighbor 172.24.0.65 soft-reconfiguration inbound
!
 address-family ipv4 multicast
 neighbor 172.24.0.65 activate
 exit-address-family
!
line vty
!
end
```

Router B detail:

```
routerB# show ip bgp sum
BGP router identifier 172.24.0.66, local AS number 2
RIB entries 1, using 112 bytes of memory
Peers 1, using 4568 bytes of memory

Neighbor        V         AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ Up/Down  State/PfxRcd
172.24.0.65     4     1      43      47        0    0    0 00:23:55        1

Total number of neighbors 1
routerB# show ip bgp ipv4 multicast 
BGP table version is 0, local router ID is 172.24.0.66
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, = multipath,
              i internal, r RIB-failure, S Stale, R Removed
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> 10.101.16.128/27 172.24.0.65              0             0 1 i

Total number of prefixes 1
```

Host 1 iperf command:

```
iperf -c 225.0.100.100 -u -t 0000 -i 1 -T 10
```

Router B iperf command:

```
iperf -s -u -B 225.0.100.100 -i 1
```

Router B still can't receive multicast packet

Comment: Enable Quagga pim plus igmp the same way you did on the other question.

Comment: So I can't just run BGP to deal with multicast routing, pimd is essential to this setup, am I correct?

Comment: In your setup, RouterA must perform multicast forwarding/replication. The easiest way to achieve this is by running Quagga pimd on it. So yes, 'modern' IP multicast usually means running PIM. Remember, PIM does not have a routing protocol in it -- it relies on correct UNICAST routing tables towards SOURCE for proper multicast function. Within an autonomous system, correct unicast routing usually requires some IGP (like OSPF). Between two AS'es, BGP is commonly used for correct UNICAST routing towards multicast SOURCE.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Multicast routing is different than your unicast routing protocols like BGP. PIM is the standard for multicast routing. Every router in the path must support a common multicast routing scheme (sparse, dense, or sparse/dense mode, and any RPs which are necessary), and that usually doesn't happen across ASes because you usually don't have control over neighbor ASes.

Normally, you would create a DVMRP tunnel from one end of the multicast path to the other end of the path, and then run multicast routing (PIM) through the tunnel. This doesn't affect your BGP configuration, other than making sure you can reach the other end of the tunnel with unicast, since the tunnel will encapsulate your multicast inside unicast packets.

[image]

Comment: I think this beyond my resource could handle, since I stated clear I only have Quagga router on both side, so there is no way I could setup DVMRP tunnel.

Comment: I don't understand why your routers can't tunnel. Routers drop multicast packets unless they have multicast routing enabled.

Comment: your theory works if I am running hardware router, but in face I am using Linux router, which makes stuff more complicated, including PIM, and I think DVMRP isn't available.

Comment: Multicast needs multicast routing, that's why you can't multicast over the Internet without a tunnel. Every router in the path would need to be configured for your multicast strategy, and that's just not going to happen.

Comment: I understand, as I said OpenVPN is a point to point tunnel already, it's not going via plain internet, please have a look my original post.

Comment: Then you need to run PIM across the tunnel. You need to enable multicast routing across your tunnel. the routers connected across the tunnel need to be PIM neighbors to send multicasts to each other (other than link-local multicasts such as a routing protocol would send).

Comment: So if I have to use PIM, what's the point for BGP multicast routing?

Comment: Are you running BGP across the tunnel, or are you running BGP with the ISP?

Comment: It's across OpenVPN tunnel

Comment: Then you could do it, but it is usually easier to run PIM which is typically a single line to enable multicast routing, and a single line to enable an interface for PIM. If you have control of every router in the path (the tunnel), you could try MBGP extensions for multicast if your routers support it. If there are any routers from the multicast source(s) layer-2 LAN(s) to the destination layer-2 LAN(s) which you do not control, you will need to tunnel across those routers. I'm not sure why you run BGP if you control both sides since an IGP is probably more responsive.

Comment: PIM implementation is more complicated on Linux, so I would like to leverage BGP instead. We run BGP because of scalability and yes we have control on all paths and routers.

Comment: Of course there is more to getting the multicast to work that just the MBGP routing. Multicast packets start with a TTL of 1 which you need the router to modify, and you probably want to control which multicast groups you allow where (it's not a good idea to transport link-local multicast packets off the link). From what I see, `pimd` and `mrouted` aren't very complicated to configure.

Comment: I don't want to hijack this post, please have a look my other post: [Post related with pimd configuration](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26308/config-pimd-on-linux-to-forward-incoming-multicast-packet-to-openvpn-tunnel-inte)

Answer (score 1):

> How exactly can I routing specific multicast address from Eth1 to OpenVPN_interface_point_B ?

This is a configuration sketch to get you started.

Host A will send multicast source network 192.168.0.0/24 to Host B by using BGP.

```
! 1.1.1.1 = Host A
! 1.1.1.2 = Host B

! Host A - partial quagga config for bgpd
router bgp 100
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 remote-as 200
 address-family ipv4 multicast 
  network 192.168.0.0/24 !! replace 192.168.0.0/24 with network for multicast source
  neighbor 1.1.1.2 activate 
 exit-address-family 

! Host B - partial quagga config for bgpd
router bgp 200
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 remote-as 100
 address-family ipv4 multicast 
  neighbor 1.1.1.1 activate 
 exit-address-family
```

Comment: This is what I read online, how does bgp 100 router know which multicast traffic should forward to bgp 200 router?!

Comment: I read your post again, the example network 192.168.0.0/24 is not the source network card IP, it's the multicast source IP; So is it possible to route specific multicast IP to other network? Also, does it means I could skip PIM setup?

Comment: For Inter-AS multicast, you usually need both: PIM+BGP. Remember that PIM relies on correct UNICAST routing for the address of the multicast source. Within one AS, this usually means PIM+IGP. Among multiple autonomous systems, IGP isn't practical then you use BGP to announce, across AS boundaries, unicast networks for multicast sources. "how does bgp 100 router know which multicast traffic should forward to bgp 200 router" --> PIM provides one answer. (There are others of course.)

Comment: @ThomasG.Lau Please remember voting up answers that are helpful for you.